# How do I configure my whm/cpanel setup so that I can have many domains using the 2 ip's I have?

Tags: ip, nameserver

I have 2 IPs and 3 domains. But whm/cpanel currently only seems to be able to assign 2 domains to my IPs.

In WHM, under Account Functions > Change Site's IP Address there is the domains I have.

I select the 3rd domain (yet to be assigned) and click 'change'.

There are 3 IP addresses there, 1 is an IP I don't own and I don't know why its there... and the other 2, are the ones I have assigned to my nameservers. **I can't select the ones I own and point my 3rd domain to either of these**, and so my 3rd domain is pointing to some random IP I don't know how to get rid of.

1. Where is this phantom IP address I don't own stored?
2. How do I configure my IPs so that I'm able to delegate more than 2 domains to my server?

Comment: I think I have just learned that I need to make an account a reseller and then create new domains through that...

Comment: Is the IP address you don't recognize 127.0.0.1? If so it is called the localhost or loopback address and is found on every unix machine as a way of talking to itself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

As you have 2 IP's in the Cpanel server, one will be the main shared IP of the server and other can be used as a dedicated or shared IP.

You can host as many domains in the main shared IP. If you need to install ssl certificate to any of the domains, that domain can be assigned the other ip as a dedicated ip.

You can see the current IP address usage from:

Main >> IP Functions >> Show IP Address Usage

You have mentioned that you are able to see a third Ip which is not yours. There can be two chances.
1) its a private ip or loopback address 127.0.0.1.
2)The ip belongs to another server, which might be added wrongly or might have been added wrongly while restoring a domain from the cpanel backup.

For the first case let the ip unchanged ...

And for the second case, you need to delete the ip from the server which can be done from the cpanel. If there is any domain assigned to that IP, assign it with another ip and delete the ip from the server which can be done from:

Main >> IP Functions >> Change Site's IP Address

Main >> IP Functions >> Show or Delete Current IP Addresses

Do post here for further queries regarding this.